# PdfReadWarning: Advanced encoding /GBK-EUC-H not implemented yet

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

PdfReadWarning: Advanced encoding /GBK-EUC-H not implemented yet

how to solve this, anyone knows?

I haven't tried anything bcs I don't know what directory should I download the missing font such as:     GBK-EUC-H, UniGB-UCS2-H

Comment: It's something that pypdf does not support so far. If you can share an example PDF, you can open an issue: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues